# `[name: string]` syntax in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm relatively new to *Typescript*, Today I faced with below syntax which I couldn't figure it out:

```
let aa:{
    [name: string]: boolean
}
aa ={
    ali: true,
    'text': false,
    3: true
}
```

What is `[name: string]: boolean` here?

At first, I thought it means we have unlimited number of properties inside `aa` object with keys types as `string`! But as you can see, I can define keys with any type.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#:~:text=Sometimes%20you%20don%E2%80%99t%20know%20all%20the%20names%20of%20a%20type%E2%80%99s%20properties%20ahead%20of%20time%2C%20but%20you%20do%20know%20the%20shape%20of%20the%20values.

Comment: you can read about [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures)

Comment: The values are accessible as `aa['ali']` and `a['3']`, so they are indeed valid as string keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Index singatures may have keys in one of three types:

- `string`
- `number`
- `symbol` (don't worry about this if you a beginner)

`number` in this case is actually just a subset of `string`, because number properties get stored on the object as strings.

This is true even in arrays. See:

```
const arr = ['a','b','c']
console.log(arr['0']) // 'a'
```

Which means that these two lines are identically equaivalent:

```
obj[3]
obj['3']
```

Which means that `string` keys include `number` keys. But if you declare `number` keys then typescript will enforce that, even though they are stored internally as strings.

```
const obj: { [key: number]: boolean } = { 3: true }

obj[3] // fine
obj['3'] // fine, because Typescript knows the string contains a number

const someString: string = '3'
obj[someString] // error
```

---

In conclusion, a `string` index signature will accept numbers, but a `number` index signature will only accept numbers or string literals that contain only diits.